# htaccess hide subdirectory from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

i want to remove/hide the subdirectory "sites" from the url

```
/profile
  /sites
    login.php
    register.php 
index.php
.htaccess
```

this:
http://localhost/profile/sites/login

to this
http://localhost/profile/login

currently i am using this to hide the .php extension

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/profile/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /profile/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: do you want to hide that directory or redirect the request?

Comment: i want to access to the login.php from this url http://localhost/profile/login not this one http://localhost/profile/sites/login

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment on the question, you could simply include the login.php from the base directory to the /sites/login.php. This will make this file run like the one in the base directory. Also see options like include_once(), require(), require_once().

I suggest you use require_once(), and don't see the need for modifying .htaccess file.

```
require_once('../login.php');
```

**UPDATE:** as per your comment on this answer, try this in the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sites/(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[See this link for reference.](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: thanks, but each file have their own content (index,login,register) i will include more pages into sites folder and for that reason i want to hide that directory this is my site http://iwnew.hol.es/ but this one doesn't have the directory sites is just /login.php,registro.php,index.php